# How to use custom gradle plugin in library module project

Tags: gradle

I have a custom gradle plugin which has uploaded into jcenter, I can use it in my android project like:

root project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    classpath 'com.myproject:projectname:1.0.1'
}
```

app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.myproject.projectname'

myconfig {
  ......
}
```

It works fine. But when I use it in my android library module, It will show error message "Gradle DSL method no found:'myconfig()'"

library module's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.myproject.projectname'

myconfig {
  ......
}
```

anyone known why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, in my gradle plugin I checked the project like this:

```
if (project.getPlugins().hasPlugin(AppPlugin)) {....}
```

so when I call it in library module, it can't goto the right branch.

Answer (score -1):

put your jar/dependencies in a folder (suppose "libs")
then show the directory

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}
dependencies {
   compile name: 'jarFile'
}
```

or something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
    compile 'package_name'
}
```

Comment: I copy the plugin.jar into module's libs folder, and config build.gradle like your method, it shows the error : Error:(11, 0) Supplied String module notation 'com. myproject.projectname' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
<a href="openFile:/Users/dfqin/Downloads/xxxxx/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: try this one: 
`compile project(':projectname')`
or
`compile files('libs/jarname.jar')`